# How to "bind" arrays that sum columns and rows of existing matrix?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm new to programming (in general) and C++ (in particular).  I'm working with arrays and trying to do the following:

```
1) create a 12x 12 array of (pseudo) random numbers
2) add a 13th row that sums up the columns
3) add a 13th column that sums up the rows
4) add a number to the diagonal of the matrix (e.g. 1 in [R1][C1], 2 in [R2][C2], etc)
5) output the adjusted matrix in step 4
```

I'm basically able to 'hack' through this (although definitely not in the most elegant way).  For # 2 and # 3 above, I use a 12x12 array and then just output two SEPARATE arrays.

**Is it possible to create one 13x13 matrix that includes the row and column of sums?
Is it possible to use pointers to simplify this?**

**If so, could someone point me in the right direction (I have no experience working with them)?**

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int N = 12;
const int M = 12;

int Matrix_M[N][M] = {0};
int rowSum[N] = {0};
int colSum[M] = {0};

void generateArray();
void Parity();
void Average();
void addError();

int main()
{
    generateArray();
    Parity();
    addError();
    Parity();

    return 0;
}

void generateArray()
{

    // generates the column headers (months of the year)

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << left << setw(5) << "Jan"
        << left << setw(5) << "Feb"
        << left << setw(5) << "Mar"
        << left << setw(5) << "Apr"
        << left << setw(5) << "May"
        << left << setw(5) << "Jun"
        << left << setw(5) << "Jul"
        << left << setw(5) << "Aug"
        << left << setw(5) << "Sep"
        << left << setw(5) << "Oct"
        << left << setw(5) << "Nov"
        << left << setw(5) << "Dec" << endl;

    cout << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---" << endl;

    // sets the seed for the number generator
    unsigned setSeed = 1023;
    srand(setSeed);

    // generates the matrix using pseudo-random numbers

    // fill the rows first
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {

        // the fill the columns
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {
            Matrix_M[i][j] = rand() % 100;

            // outputs the raw matrix
            cout << left << setw(4) << Matrix_M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void Parity()
{

    cout << "The parity values are:" << endl << endl;

    // generates the column headers (months of the year)

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << left << setw(5) << "Jan"
        << left << setw(5) << "Feb"
        << left << setw(5) << "Mar"
        << left << setw(5) << "Apr"
        << left << setw(5) << "May"
        << left << setw(5) << "Jun"
        << left << setw(5) << "Jul"
        << left << setw(5) << "Aug"
        << left << setw(5) << "Sep"
        << left << setw(5) << "Oct"
        << left << setw(5) << "Nov"
        << left << setw(5) << "Dec" << endl;

    cout << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---" << endl;

    cout << left << setw(12) << "Columns" << left << setw(12) << "Rows" << endl;
    cout << left << setw(12) << "-------" << left << setw(12) << "----" << endl;

    // sums the row and column elements

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
        {
            rowSum[i] += Matrix_M[i][j];
            colSum[i] += Matrix_M[j][i];
        }

        // outputs the sums
        cout <<  setw(5) << colSum[i];
        cout << left << setw(65) << rowSum[i] << endl;
    }
}


void addError()
{
    // some explanatory text
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "The following matrix introduces an error along the diagonal" << endl;

    // generates the column headers (months of the year)

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << left << setw(5) << "Jan"
        << left << setw(5) << "Feb"
        << left << setw(5) << "Mar"
        << left << setw(5) << "Apr"
        << left << setw(5) << "May"
        << left << setw(5) << "Jun"
        << left << setw(5) << "Jul"
        << left << setw(5) << "Aug"
        << left << setw(5) << "Sep"
        << left << setw(5) << "Oct"
        << left << setw(5) << "Nov"
        << left << setw(5) << "Dec" << endl;

    cout << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---"
        << left << setw(5) << "---" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        {

            // introduces an error to the previously-generated number in the original matrix
            // adds 1 to [R1][C1], adds 2 to [R2][C2], adds 3 to [R1][C1] ... adds 12 to [R12][C12]
            if (i == j)
            {
                Matrix_M[i][j] += (i+1)*1;
            }

            // outputs the matrix containing errors 
            cout << left << setw(4) << Matrix_M[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
-Ryan

Answer (score 0):

In general the use of **arrays** is depreciated in **C++**. Use for example a `std::vector` instead:

```
const int N = 12;
const int M = 12;

std::vector<int> matrix = std::vector<int>((N+1)*(M+1),0);    //creating the matrix adding one extra row and column for the sums;

//filling the matrix
for(int ii=0; ii<N; ii++)
{
    for(int jj=0; jj<M; jj++)
    {
        matrix[ii*(M+1) + jj] = rand() % 100;
        matrix[ii*(M+1) + M] += matrix[ii*(M+1) + jj];    //updating the sum;
    }
}
```

This computes the sums of all rows, accordingly you can introduce an extra loop to compute the sums of the columns.

Comment: I know that vectors are the way to go.  But, technically, we haven't learned about them yet.  Is there a way to do this using arrays and pointers?

Comment: Sure, just do the same with an array: `int matrix[(N+1)*(M+1)] = {0}`. The following steps are the same.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.  When I output << cout << Matrix_M[i*j] << " "; I'm seeing some strange results.  Is Matrix_M[i*j] the correct output?  Or, did I miss something?

Comment: No I don't think `Matrix_M[i*j]` is what you want to ouput. If `i` denotes the row number and `j` the column you can print out the corresponding element using `Matrix_M[i*(M+1) + j]` if `M` is the number of columns *without* the last sum-column.
Alternatively you can use `int Matrix_M[N+1][M+1] = {0}` and access the element in row `i` and column `j` simply by `Matrix_M[i][j]`.